# Copy array list to another array list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sails.js

I want to copy the below array list

```
$scope.medicinelist = [

{medicine: 'AMLOPRES 5MG TABLET'},
{medicine: 'ARGIPREG SACHET'},
{medicine: 'ALCIPRO 500MG TABLET'} ,
{medicine: 'PROLOMET AM 50MG TABLET'},
{medicine: 'PROLOMET AM 5MG TABLET'},
{medicine: 'AB PHYLLINE 200MG TABLET SR'} ,
{medicine: 'ACIVIR 800MG TABLET DT'},

{medicine: 'CEPODEM AZ TABLET'},
{medicine: 'ECOSPRIN AV 10MG CAPSULE'},
{medicine: 'ECOSPRIN AV 150MG CAPSULE'} ,
{medicine: 'ATORLIP 40MG TABLET'},
{medicine: 'AMTAS 5MG TABLET'},
{medicine: 'ARKAMIN 100MG TABLET'} ,
{medicine: 'AMPOXIN 500MG INJECTION'} ];
```

to the following array list

```
 $rootScope.medicinedrop = [
    // {
    //   medicine: 'you try to drop me somewhere'
    // }

    ];
```

i am also using $scope.maedicinedrop for drag drop operation from another list, after coping i am loosing that functionality that is not able to drop items into it from another list after copy.

on button press

```
$scope.copy = function(){
    console.log($scope.pastprescription)
    $scope.medicinedrop.unshift($scope.pastprescriptions.medicine);

     }
```

but after pressing putton it just show blank that in console data is copied but not displayed.

for drag drop i am using dragular as:

```
dragularService([containerLeft_Medicine], {
      containersModel: [$scope.allmedicines],
      copy: true,
      //move only from left to right  
      accepts: accepts
    });

    dragularService([containerRight_Medicine], {
      containersModel: [$scope.medicinedrop],
      removeOnSpill: true,
      //move only from left to right  
      accepts: accepts
    });
```

ejs file for it is as :

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-repeat="medicine_name in medicinedrop"
          value="{{medicine_name.medicine}}" />
```

Comment: `but after pressing putton it just show blank that in console data is copied but not displayed.` what does that mean?

Answer (score 3):

```
$Scope.medicinedrop = angular.copy($scope.medicinelist);
```

Comment: I have tried both the options they are working but actualy i am using $scope.maedicinedrop for drag drop operation also and after doing that i am loosing that functionality that is not able to drop items into it from another list.

Comment: @RAJDUBEY It's difficult to understand this `drag and drop` functionality that you're talking about in just one line of statement. Can you please ask a saperate question where you show us all the code and we can work out on that?

Answer (score 1):

Create a deep copy of source, which should be an object or an array.

> angular.copy(source, [destination]);

```
$scope.medicinedrop = angular.copy($scope.medicinelist);
```

Refrence : [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply assign first list to second

```
 $Scope.medicinedrop = $scope.medicinelist;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.medicinelist = [

{medicine: 'AMLOPRES 5MG TABLET'},
{medicine: 'ARGIPREG SACHET'},
{medicine: 'ALCIPRO 500MG TABLET'} ,
{medicine: 'PROLOMET AM 50MG TABLET'},
{medicine: 'PROLOMET AM 5MG TABLET'},
{medicine: 'AB PHYLLINE 200MG TABLET SR'} ,
{medicine: 'ACIVIR 800MG TABLET DT'},

{medicine: 'CEPODEM AZ TABLET'},
{medicine: 'ECOSPRIN AV 10MG CAPSULE'},
{medicine: 'ECOSPRIN AV 150MG CAPSULE'} ,
{medicine: 'ATORLIP 40MG TABLET'},
{medicine: 'AMTAS 5MG TABLET'},
{medicine: 'ARKAMIN 100MG TABLET'} ,
{medicine: 'AMPOXIN 500MG INJECTION'} ];
  
$scope.medicinedrop = [{medicine: 'TEST'}];
$scope.medicinedrop = $scope.medicinelist.concat($scope.medicinedrop);
console.log($scope.medicinedrop); 
});
```

```html
Try this,
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    
  </body>
```

Comment: the copy is working but not able to perform drag and drop after coping

Comment: What you are doing for drag and drop

Comment: i am using dragular drag drop .

Comment: dragularService([containerLeft_Medicine], {
      containersModel: [$scope.allmedicine],
      copy: true,
      //move only from left to right  
      accepts: accepts
    });

    dragularService([containerRight_Medicine], {
      containersModel: [$scope.medicinedrop],
      removeOnSpill: true,
      //move only from left to right  
      accepts: accepts
    });